# How To Change List of Chars To String?

Tags: string, f#

In F# I want to transform a list of chars into a string.  Consider the following code:

```
let lChars = ['a';'b';'c']
```

If I simply do *lChars.ToString*, I get *"['a';'b';'c']"*.  I'm trying to get *"abc"*.  I realize I could probably do a List.reduce to get the effect I'm looking for but it seems like there should be some primitive built into the library to do this.

To give a little context to this, I'm doing some manipulation on individual characters in a string and when I'm done, I want to display the resulting string.

I've tried googling this and no joy that way.  Do I need to just bite the bullet and build a List.reduce expression to do this transformation or is there some more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Have you tried

```
System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(lChars))
```

Comment: new System.String(lchars |> Array.of_list) works just as well too.

Comment: @JaredPar, thanks!  Just what the doctor ordered.  I figured there must be some simple way to get at the string I wanted.

@Juliet, you should have posted that as an answer :-)  I would have voted it up because it's also an excellent suggestion.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4 or later, `System.String.Concat(lChars)` also does the trick.

Comment: `let result = lChars |> Array.ofList |> String` works too in F# 4.0

Answer (score 9):

How many ways can you build a string in F#? 
Here's another handful:

```
let chars = ['H';'e';'l';'l';'o';',';' ';'w';'o';'r';'l';'d';'!']

//Using an array builder
let hw1 = new string [|for c in chars -> c|]

//StringBuilder-Lisp-like approach
open System.Text
let hw2 = 
    string (List.fold (fun (sb:StringBuilder) (c:char) -> sb.Append(c)) 
                      (new StringBuilder())
                       chars)

//Continuation passing style
let hw3 =
    let rec aux L k =
        match L with
        | [] -> k ""
        | h::t -> aux t (fun rest -> k (string h + rest) )
    aux chars id
```

**Edit:** timings may be interesting? I turned hw1..3 into functions and fed them a list of 500000 random characters:

- hw1: 51ms
- hw2: 16ms
- hw3: er... long enough to grow a beard? I think it just ate all of my memory.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't see this one here, so:

```
let stringFromCharList (cl : char list) =
    String.concat "" <| List.map string cl
```

"" is just an empty string.

FSI output:

```
> stringFromCharList ['a'..'d'];;
val it : string = "abcd"
```

EDIT:

Didn't like this syntax coming back to this so here's a more canonically functional one:

```
['a'..'z'] |> List.map string |> List.reduce (+)
```

Comment: The last version is nice and everything, but it is quadratic in the size of list.

Comment: /shrug don't use it on big lists, I guess. How would you reduce the time complexity?

Answer (score 2):

```
['a';'b';'c'] |> List.fold_left (fun acc c -> acc ^ (string c)) ""
```

Edited:
Here is yet another funny way to do your task:

```
type t =
  | N
  | S of string
  static member Zero
    with get() = N
  static member (+) (a: t, b: t) = 
    match a,b with
      | S a, S b -> S (a+b)
      | N, _ -> b
      | _, N -> a

let string_of_t = function
  |N -> ""
  |S s -> s

let t_of_char c = S (string c)

['a'; 'b'; 'c'] |> List.map t_of_char |> List.sum |> string_of_t
```

Sadly, just extending System.String with 'Zero' member does not allow to use List.sum with strings.

Edited (answer to Juilet):
Yes, you are right, left fold is slow. But i know more slow right fold :) :

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack"

List.fold_right (String.make 1 >> (^)) ['a';'b';'c'] ""
```

and of course there is fast and simple:

```
new System.String(List.to_array ['1';'2';'3'])
```

Comment: One thing @ssp, I did try concatenating a string with the ^ operator and the compiler gave me a warning about OCaml compatibility.  That is, it warned me that I should use + to concatenate strings.

Comment: fold_left is fun, but you need to remember that appending strings is O(n), and appending strings one char at a time is O(n^2)!

Answer (score 1):

And i used 'sprintf' seems to me easier:

```
let t = "Not what you might expect"
let r = [ for i in "aeiou" -> i]
let q = [for a in t do if not (List.exists (fun x -> x=a) r) then yield a]
let rec m  = function  [] -> "" | h::t ->  (sprintf "%c" h) + (m t)
printfn "%A"  (m q)
```

Comment: What are the curly braces for?

Comment: `let r = List.ofSeq "aeiou"` seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me:

```
let charList = ["H";"E";"L";"L";"O"]

let rec buildString list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> "" 
    | head::tail -> head + (buildString tail)

let resultBuildString = buildString charList
```

Comment: Note - this is a list of strings, not chars.  Also, you have just reimplemented List.fold

Comment: This wasn't the right answer but it came in useful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```ml
    [|'w'; 'i'; 'l'; 'l'|]
    |> Array.map string
    |> Array.reduce (+)
```

or as someone else posted:

```ml
    System.String.Concat([|'w'; 'i'; 'l'; 'l'|])
```